# Error while CI from TFS to Azure

Tags: tfsbuild

## Problem

I am new to TFS and Azure I am trying to CI to build a project into TFS but it fails I don't know how to resolved this issue.

## Image

[image]

Comment: Did you add some msbuild parameters in that build step? Could you provide the steps to reproduce this issue?

Comment: These are the parameters.


/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package/p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true/p:PackageLocation="$(BuildConfiguration)"

Comment: Your parameters seems ok. Please share your .xproj file here, it there a task called "GetAllPublishProperties"? Delete it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You missed some blank space between the arguments you entered in the VS Build Step. Make sure that you have the blank space between every arguments. Try with the arguments below:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(BuildConfiguration)"
```